# Let's Encrypt with Traefik

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I try to use Let's Encrypt with Traefik, but here are Traefik's log:

```
Looking for provided certificate to validate [rancher.foo.bar]...
No provided certificate found for domains [rancher.foo.bar], get ACME certificate.
Looking for an existing ACME challenge for rancher.foo.bar...
No certificate found or generated for rancher.foo.bar
http2: server: error reading preface from client 1.2.3.4:60876: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

Here is my config:

```
traefikLogsFile = "/tmp/traefik.log"
logLevel = "DEBUG" # DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
[accessLog]
filePath = "/tmp/access.log"


[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]

# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL.
[acme]
email = "foo@foo.bar"
storage = "/tmp/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"


[api]
entryPoint = "traefik"
dashboard = true


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "foo.bar"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = true
usebindportip = true
swarmmode = false
```

Traefik providers:

```
{
  "docker": {
    "backends": {
      "backend-rancher": {
        "servers": {
          "server-rancher": {
            "url": "http://172.17.0.3:8080",
            "weight": 0
          }
        },
        "loadBalancer": {
          "method": "wrr"
        }
      }
    },
    "frontends": {
      "frontend-Host-rancher-foo-bar-0": {
        "entryPoints": [
          "http"
        ],
        "backend": "backend-rancher",
        "routes": {
          "route-frontend-Host-rancher-foo-bar-0": {
            "rule": "Host:rancher.foo.bar"
          }
        },
        "passHostHeader": true,
        "priority": 0,
        "basicAuth": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: In fact, we need more logs to understand your problem. What the logs say here, is that your certificate had never been generated.
You enabled onHostRule, do you have a backend with an Host rule for foo.bar.baz ?

Comment: I updated my message and add traefik providers

Comment: Could you add your full TOML configuration?

Comment: Ok I updated my config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use onHostRule, this will request a certificate from Let's Encrypt for each frontend with a Host rule. But you need your frontent to be assigned to the TLS entrypoint of ACME. (here `https`).

So in your docker labels, you need to add `https` on the frontend.entrypoint.

Comment: Ok, I succeed to use it like this: `--label traefik.protocol=http --label traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https`

Comment: Does this [break the let's encrypt `http` challenge](https://community.traefik.io/t/https-redirection-without-breaking-letsencrypt-http-challenge/11215/3)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you add:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
```

on the top of your TOML file.

Comment: I did it, same result.